# Set HTML radio input checked using its id via c#

Tags: c#, html, radio-button

I am programming an HTML page using C#.

And, I need to set an input of type radio to be checked using its "id" via the C# code

Here is an example of the radio input:

```
<input id="factor<%= assessmentFactorId %>Score1" name="<%= assessmentFactorId %>" type="radio" value="1">
```

*Notice that when I use (runat="server"), I get an error since I need to use some C# code within the input tag

what is the C# statement I can use to set this input checked again using its "id"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to set runat="server" property to checkbox then you can find Checkbox using HtmlControls like below

We have use HtmlInputCheckBox

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton factorScore1= item as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton;
```

now check or uncheck your checkbox

```
factorScore1.Checked=true;
```

Comment: Can you clarify more please? Where should I add the HtmlInputCheckBox Code? In the CS code? If so, I am getting "The name 'item' does not exist in the current context" Error

Answer (score 0):

You Need to Use `runat="server"` so you can access it on Server Side

.aspx code

```
<input id="factorScore1" runat="server"  name="assessmentFactorId" 
type="radio" value="1">
```

.CS code

```
factorScore1.Checked=true;


if(factorScore1.Checked)
{

}
```

Comment: The input name not recognized in the CS code. Also, I need to set this using the input "id"

Comment: @Ghadeer All elements on server side are access by ID

Answer (score 0):

you have use `runat=server` attribute to access it code file(.cs).

```
<input id="factorScore1" name="assessmentFactorId" type="radio" value="1" 
 runat="server">
```

Now, set checked state with true or false what ever you want.

```
factorScore1.Checked=true;
```